# Problema com o bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Galera to com um problema aqui no meu TCC, estou criando uma aplicação web, no front-end do meu projeto tenho uma tela que contem uma tab com dois campos, ao clicar em uma aparece um formulário para o usuário pre-encher e se clicar na outra outro formulário.
O meu problema é que está aparecendo os dois formulários nas duas tabs.
Alguém tem alguma dica???

```
<script>
 $(".pagination").find('a').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(e){                
    e.preventDefault();
    $("a[href='#notas']").tab('show');
  });
});
</script>
<ul id="tabs_sistem" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li id="tab_prest_contas" class="active">
    <a href="#prest_contas" data-toggle="tab">Prestação de Contas</a>
  </li>
  <li id="tab_notas">
    <a href="#notas" data-toggle="tab">Notas Fiscais</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

como pediram... ta ai o código...estou usando um script em javascript pra fazer as tabs funcionarem e adicionei um id em cada formulario...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

nessa imagem ta o script que to usando e o html das tabs... nos formulários, coloquei dentro de uma div em cada com os ids que aparecem na imagem...

Comment: Não estou a perceber o seu problema se poder explicar melhor onde está o problema. Como fazes os show de um form e do outro?

Comment: Tipo o meu problema é q em cada tab deveria mostrar 1 formulário diferente mas nas duas ta mostrando os dois... e eu não tenho a menor ideia de onde esta o erro estou usando esse tipo de código pela primeira vez... então estou bem perdido...

Comment: Seu código está dizendo para "qualquer link que for clicado, abra a tab `#notas`", o que é um erro mas acredito não estar relacionado ao seu problema. Seu HTML é que deve estar incorreto, tem como postá-lo inteiro em algum lugar? (pastebin por exemplo, mas se puder usar algo como o StackSnippets ou jsFiddle para criar um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), tanto melhor!)

Comment: @JesseSeffrin eu vejo ai um jQuery que só trata a tab notas e o jQuery para a outra tab?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sup>A tua *markup* indica que estás a fazer uso do *plugin* [Togglable tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) do Bootstrap.</sup>

## O teu problema

Se analisares o teu código e verificares na documentação do Bootstrap para o *plugin* [Togglable tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), a forma como estás a ativar o mesmo é incorreta por dois motivos:

1. Quando usas:

   ```
   <a href="#prest_contas" data-toggle="tab">Prestação de Contas</a>
   ```

   Estás a ativar o *plugin* através do atributo `data`, não precisas de usar JavaScript, mas na tua pergunta estás a usar ambos.

   **Na documentação:**

   > You can activate a tab or pill navigation without writing any JavaScript by simply specifying `data-toggle="tab"` or `data-toggle="pill"` on an element.

   Que traduzido:

   > Podes ativar a navegação *tab* ou *pill* sem escrever nenhum JavaScript simplesmente especificando `dados-toggle="tab"` ou `data-toggle="pílula"` num elemento.
2. Quando ativas via JavaScript:

   Cada *trigger* tem que ser instanciado independentemente, algo que tu estás a tentar fazer mas de forma incorreta dado que estás a relacionar todos os separadores para o mesmo painel:

   **Teu código atual**

   ```
   /* Este teu código precisa de ser ajustado
    */
   $(".pagination").find('a').each(function(){
       $(this).click(function(e){                
           e.preventDefault();
           $("a[href='#notas']").tab('show');   // ←-- A falhar aqui porque
       });                                      //     esta chamada ativa o
   });                                          //     separador via "nome"
                                                //     e é sempre ID #notas
   ```

   **Teu código retificado**

   [Ver exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/5jrnoa8z/)

   ```
   /* Dentro do contentor `pagination` localizar
    * os triggers de cada painel e associar os
    * mesmos ao seu separador
    */
   $('.pagination .nav-tabs a').each(function() {

       $(this).click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();

           $(this).tab('show'); // apresentar o meu painel
       });
   });
   ```

   O *trigger* sabe quem é o seu painel porque o mesmo está referenciado no atributo `href`.

   ```js
    /* Dentro do contentor `pagination` localizar
     * os triggers de cada painel e associar os
     * mesmos ao seu separador
     */
    $('.pagination .nav-tabs a').each(function() {
        
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
           
            $(this).tab('show'); // apresentar o meu painel
        });
    });
   ```

   ```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="pagination">
        <ul id="tabs_sistem" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li id="tab_prest_contas" class="active">
                <a href="#prest_contas">Prestação de Contas</a>
            </li>
            <li id="tab_notas">
                <a href="#notas">Notas Fiscais</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="prest_contas">
                <p>Painel para Prestação de Contas</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="notas">
                <p>Painel para Notas Fiscais</p>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   ```

---

## Considerações gerais

#### *Markup* do *plugin*

O mesmo tem uma *markup* especifica para que as coisas funcionem como esperado:

```
<!-- Separadores de navegação -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="#idMeuPainel1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Formulário 1</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#idMeuPainel2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Formulário 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Paineis dos separadores -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="idMeuPainel1">
    <!-- o teu formulário 1 aqui -->
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="idMeuPainel2">
    <!-- o teu formulário 2 aqui -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Como podes reparar pelo exemplo em cima, cada *trigger* diz respeito a um painel e a relação entre o *trigger* e o painel é realizada pelo ID do painel:

```
<a href="#idMeuPainel2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Formulário 2</a>
         │└────┬─────┘
         │     │       
         │     └────────────────────────────────┐ <!-- exatamente iguais -->
         ↓                                      │
<!-- # = indicador de ID -->                    │
                                          ┌─────┴────┐
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="idMeuPainel2"></div>
```

**Nota:** Cada *trigger* tem que apontar para um único painel e os IDs tem que ser unicos na página inteira.

#### Primeira Tab Ativa

A classe de CSS `active` é a responsável por apresentar um separador aberto ao iniciar o *plugin*.

A mesma deverá estar presente tanto no *parent* do *trigger* como no elemento que serve de painel.

No exemplo nesta resposta, o *parent* do *trigger* é uma  e o painel é uma `<div/>`:

```
<li role="presentation" class="active"> <!-- ... --> </li>

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="idMeuPainel1"> <!-- ... --> </div>
```

**Nota:** Apenas um *parent* de um *trigger* e apenas um painel podem estar com a classe `active` ou surgem comportamentos não esperados como é o caso de ao carregar a página aparecerem múltiplos painéis visíveis.

#### Outros problemas de aparecerem dois painel

Muitas vezes também estão a aparecer dois painéis por falhas na *markup* ou por duplicação de `id`:

- Falha na *markup*

  Se tiveres dois painéis mas o primeiro não estiver com as tags de fecho presentes ou na ordem correta, o HTML vai ser mal interpretado e quando esse painel fica visível, o que está a baixo fica também.
- Duplicação de `id`

  Se dois painéis estiverem com o mesmo `id`, ao chamares esse `id` vão aparecer os dois painéis.

Comment: bah... valeu amigo... vou tentar...

Comment: Deu Certo amigo... muito obrigado... tipo eu tenho que entregar meu tcc segunda-feira a parte escrita e meu orientador pediu essa tela pronta... e agora graças a vc eu consegui... muito obrigado mesmo...

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta! +1